# haskell equivalent for loop with if statements

Tags: function, haskell, boolean, iteration

HI noob question here but im learning Haskell

I'm trying to understand how to iterate 0 through until n and return false if the iteration contains 5 other wise return true

here is my method

```
 Fivecount :: Integral a => a -> Bool

 isfivecount z =  False
```

want something like this in JAVA

```
method boolean (n)
{
for(int i = 2; i < n; i++){
  if(i == 5){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance FRIENDS :) an explanation would be cool too, just really trying to understand Haskell.

Comment: Note that your Java code contradicts your English explanation.

Comment: Note that learning Haskell by translating Java is one of the worst methods, which will often produce non idiomatic code. This holds for any languages, in general: learning Java by translating Haskell will also lead to weird, non idiomatic code. I recommend to read a Haskell tutorial (e.g. LYAH) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some good answers already, and you’ve already accepted one, but please allow me to go into some more detail about why some different versions are equivalent to the `for` loop.  (Warning: a bunch of untested code.)  Keep in mind that you won’t normally write a functional program by starting with an imperative approach and converting it.  You’d use different strategies, such as tail recursion.  In fact, strict tail recursion can do everything a `for` loop can.

The current code sample you give does not appear to match your specification, because it always returns `false`.  It sounds as if a simple `return (i >= 5)` would do it, but since this is a learning example, let’s write a `for` loop:

```
public static boolean containsFive( int n )
{
  for ( int i = 0; i <= n; i++ )
    if ( i == 5 )
      return true;

  return false;
}
```

A `for` loop is the same as a `while` loop, as so:

```
public static boolean containsFive( int n )
{
  int i = 0;

  while ( i <= n ) {
    if ( i == 5 )
      return true;

    i++;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Keeping it simple, one thing we can do is turn the `do` loop into a function call, with `i` as a parameter:

```
public static boolean containsFive(int n)
{
  return containsFive( n, 0 );
}

private static boolean containsFive( int n, int i )
{
  if (i > n)
    return false;
  else if (i == 5)
    return true;
  else
    return containsFive( n, i+1 );
}
```

Each iteration of the loop is now replaced with a tail-recursive call.  This solution has a close translation into Haskell:

```
containsFive :: Integral a => a -> Bool
containsFive n = containsFive' 0 where
  containsFive' i =
    if      i > n  then false
    else if i == 5 then true
    else                containsFive' (i+1)
```

You’re more likely to see this written with pattern guards, however:

```
containsFive :: Integral a => a -> Bool
containsFive n = containsFive' 0 where
  containsFive' i | i > n     = false
                  | i == 5    = true
                  | otherwise = containsFive' (i+1)
```

One subtle difference is that Java will evaluate expressions, such as `n-1` or `i+1`, strictly, and Haskell by default evaluates them lazily.  However, the compiler might be able to tell that it’s slightly more optimal to make the parameter strict, and if not, there are a few different ways to tell it.  We could also have passed in `n` as a second parameter, like we did in Java, but since our helper function here is nested, `n` remains in scope and passing it again is unnecessary.

Another is that the typeclass `Integral` is more like an `interface` and covers some classes that are bigger and more complicated than an `Int`.  An `Integer` is more like a bignum.  And, if you’re wondering, you could specify `containsFive' :: Integral a => a -> a -> Bool`, but the compiler can deduce from the expression `i > n` that `i` must have the same type as `n`, which is some kind of `Integral`.  The `==` operator is from the `Eq` typeclass and `>` is from the `Ord` typeclass.  Numeric constants in Haskell are defined in terms of a `fromInteger` function that every kind of `Num` implements, so in context, the constants `0`, `1` and `5` will automatically convert to the type of `i`, whatever that is.  The `+` operator is also from `Num`.  Since we specified that that type implements `Integral`, it must also implement `Num`, `Eq` and `Ord`, so we’re fine.

So let’s handwave all that and assume each recursive call just passes in the value of `i` in a register, like in Java.

First, the code runs the recursive function with `i` initially set to `0`. The code generator can already optimize away the overhead of creating a stack frame for each function call, and just re-use the same one each time—we’re calling the exact same function, so it has the same number of arguments of the same types and needs the same size stack.  It doesn’t need to change the value of `n`, but it needs to set the register containing `i` to `i+1`.  Then, it jumps back to the beginning of the function and runs it again until the loop condition fails or the test `i == 5` passes and it terminates early.  That’s exactly the same operation as our original loop!  (Well, unless it was aggressively optimized.)

You’re even more likely to see this simplified by counting *down*, as in:

```
containsFive :: Integral a => a -> Bool
containsFive 5 = true
containsFive n | n > 0     = containsFive (n-1)
               | otherwise = false
```

You could also count down in Java as well, by writing `for ( int i = n; i > 0; i-- )` and some C programmers I’ve talked to swear by it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using a library function, one possibility would be to use [`any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:any) to write something like the following:

```
anyFivesInRangeZeroTo :: (Eq a, Num a, Enum a) => a -> Bool
anyFivesInRangeZeroTo n = not $ any (5 ==) [0..n]
```

Another option, if you'd prefer a more loop-like approach, would be to use recursion:

```
anyFivesInRange' :: (Enum t, Ord t, Num t) => t -> Bool
anyFivesInRangeZeroTo' nn = 
  let
    iter 5 _ = False
    iter n nn = if n < nn then iter (succ n) nn else True
  in 
    iter 0 nn
```

This is equivalent to a for loop whose index starts at zero and is incremented by one until either it finds `5` (by pattern matching on the helper function's first argument) and returns `False` or reaches the loop boundary and returns `True`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally if you're trying to iterate through a list (in this case the list `[0..n]`) you're talking about a fold. In this case, the fold is over the function:

```
\n acc -> n /= 5 && acc
```

or, simply

```
(&&) . (/=5)
```

so your function becomes:

```
isFiveCount n = foldr ((&&) . (/=5)) True [0..n]
```

or point-free

```
isFiveCount = foldr ((&&) . (/=5)) True . enumFromTo 0
```

---

To write this out with explicit recursion, you'll just keep incrementing your value until you either reach `n` or `5`.

```
isFiveCount n = go 0
  where
  go 5 = False  -- base case FAIL
  go x | x == n    = True  -- base case SUCCESS
       | otherwise = go (x+1)
```

---

Though of course through simple logic you can reduce this all to

```
isFiveCount n = n < 5
```